# Run While Loop Through All Distinct Values of A Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

This is an example MYSQL result

```
+----+---+
|  A | B |
+----+---+
|  1 | 1 |
|  1 | 2 | 
|  2 | 3 |
|  2 | 4 |
|  3 | 5 |
+----+---+
```

I would like to run through every distinct in Column A and do something utilizing the values in Column B.
Let's say A has userids and B has foods. I would like to grab all the foods that user 1 likes and then shoot an email to 1, then grab all the foods that user 2 likes and email to her, and so forth. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what is you desired output in this case?

Comment: What have you tried? If you actually have tried something please post all your relevant code so we can give you a specific answer. Also you never specified variable A and B as food or email please elaborate what you want more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want comma separated values, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT A, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B) foodList
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY A
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c724f/1)

Other Link

- [GROUP BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I think this might be what I am looking for, I totally forgot about group_concat!

Comment: i hope so `:D` anyway you can all foods in csv on the result.